# Spring-WS generates WSDL without operations

Tags: java, web-services, wsdl, spring-ws

Spring-WS generates WSDL without operations in binding tag... Do you know why?

There is my spring-ws-service.xml:

```
    <import resource="classpath*:application-context.xml" />

    <!-- Register PayloadRootAnnotationMethodEndpointMapping -->
    <bean class="org.springframework.ws.server.endpoint.mapping.PayloadRootAnnotationMethodEndpointMapping" />

    <!-- Register Endpoint -->
    <bean id="tasktablerServiceEndpoint" class="tasktabler.mpk.service.TasktablerServiceEndpoint" />

    <!-- Configure XML Marshaller -->
    <bean class="org.springframework.ws.server.endpoint.adapter.GenericMarshallingMethodEndpointAdapter">
        <constructor-arg ref="marshaller" />
    </bean>

    <bean id="marshaller" class="org.springframework.oxm.jaxb.Jaxb2Marshaller">
        <property name="classesToBeBound">
            <list>
                <value>tasktabler.mpk.databinding.OptimizeRequest</value>
            </list>
        </property>
    </bean>

    <!-- Add automatic WSDL generation support -->
    <bean id="tasktabler" class="org.springframework.ws.wsdl.wsdl11.DefaultWsdl11Definition">
        <property name="schema" ref="schema" />
        <property name="portTypeName" value="tasktabler" />
        <property name="locationUri" value="http://localhost:8080/tasktabler" />
        <property name="targetNamespace" value="http://tasktabler" />
    </bean>

    <bean id="schema" class="org.springframework.xml.xsd.SimpleXsdSchema">
        <property name="xsd" value="/WEB-INF/schema.xsd" />
    </bean>
```

And there is wsdl binding part of WSDL:

```
   <wsdl:binding name="tasktablerSoap11" type="tns:tasktabler">
      <soap:binding style="document" transport="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/http"/>
   </wsdl:binding>
```

Thanks in advance,
Etam.

Comment: Could you please add the generated WSDL?

Answer (score 31, accepted):

DefaultWsdl11Definition attempts to auto-generate the WSDL by examining the types in your schema. If your schema doesn't fit its expected patterns, it won't do a good job of it.

From [the documentation](http://static.springsource.org/spring-ws/sites/1.5/reference/html/server.html#server-automatic-wsdl-exposure):

> The DefaultWsdl11Definition which
>   builds a WSDL from a XSD schema. This
>   definition iterates over all element
>   elements found in the schema, and
>   creates a message for all elements.
>   Next, it creates WSDL operation for
>   all messages that end with the defined
>   request or response suffix. The
>   default request suffix is Request; the
>   default response suffix is Response,
>   though these can be changed by setting
>   the requestSuffix and responseSuffix 
>   properties, respectively. It also
>   builds a portType, binding, and
>   service based on the operations.
>
> For instance, if our Orders.xsd schema
>   defines the GetOrdersRequest and
>   GetOrdersResponse elements, the
>   XsdBasedSoap11Wsdl4jDefinitionBuilder
>   will create a GetOrdersRequest and
>   GetOrdersResponse message, and a
>   GetOrders operation, which is put in a
>   Orders port type.

Comment: Thanks for mentioning `requestSuffix` and `responseSuffix`