# understand spring-ws, integration with spring-mvc and automatic generation of wsdl

Tags: java, spring, web-services, wsdl, spring-ws

i want learn spring-ws with automatic generation of wsdl files, i know that is a lot of tutorials, i tried them, my favorite example is :

[github projet](https://github.com/Jibbylala/SpringWS)

It works well, but i tried to ajust that solution for my needs, and it doesnt work, i dont know why, and it is question for you, what is wrong here?

I was changed:

- models (oxm package in github project) - schema.xsd (ecommerce.xsd in github project) as well
- EndpointClass
- remove classes: SubscriptionPort.java and SubscriptionPortService.java (I noticed that are not needed for proper operation) (when remove from github project everything was good)

and my generated wsdl file have no wsdl:operation tag (should be in PortType tag)...

```
<wsdl:definitions xmlns:wsdl="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/wsdl/" xmlns:sch="http://localhost:8080/ws/schema/oss" xmlns:soap="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/wsdl/soap/" xmlns:tns="http://localhost:8080/ws/schema/oss" targetNamespace="http://localhost:8080/ws/schema/oss">
   <wsdl:types>
      <xs:schema xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" attributeFormDefault="qualified" elementFormDefault="qualified" targetNamespace="http://localhost:8080/ws/schema/oss" version="1.0">
         <xs:complexType name="deliverShortMessageRequest">
            <xs:sequence>
               <xs:element minOccurs="0" name="parameters">
                  <xs:complexType>
                     <xs:sequence>
                        <xs:element name="sms" type="tns:deliverShortMessage"/>
                     </xs:sequence>
                  </xs:complexType>
               </xs:element>
            </xs:sequence>
         </xs:complexType>
         <xs:complexType name="deliverShortMessageResponse">
            <xs:sequence>
               <xs:element name="deliverShortMessageReturn" type="xs:boolean"/>
            </xs:sequence>
         </xs:complexType>
         <xs:complexType name="deliverShortMessage">
            <xs:sequence>
               <xs:element minOccurs="0" name="sms" type="tns:smsMessage"/>
            </xs:sequence>
         </xs:complexType>
         <xs:complexType name="smsMessage">
            <xs:sequence>
               <xs:element minOccurs="0" name="content" type="xs:string"/>
            </xs:sequence>
         </xs:complexType>
      </xs:schema>
   </wsdl:types>
   <wsdl:portType name="SubscriptionPort"></wsdl:portType>
   <wsdl:binding name="SubscriptionPortSoap11"      type="tns:SubscriptionPort">
      <soap:binding style="document"      transport="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/http"/>
   </wsdl:binding>
   <wsdl:service name="SubscriptionPortService">
      <wsdl:port binding="tns:SubscriptionPortSoap11" name="SubscriptionPortSoap11">
         <soap:address location="/"/>
      </wsdl:port>
   </wsdl:service>
```

schema.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" standalone="yes"?>
<xs:schema version="1.0" xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema"
    elementFormDefault="qualified"
    attributeFormDefault="qualified"
    targetNamespace="http://localhost:8080/ws/schema/oss"
    xmlns:tns="http://localhost:8080/ws/schema/oss">

  <xs:complexType name="deliverShortMessageRequest">
    <xs:sequence>
      <xs:element name="parameters" minOccurs="0">
        <xs:complexType>
          <xs:sequence>
            <xs:element name="sms" type="tns:deliverShortMessage"/>
          </xs:sequence>
        </xs:complexType>
      </xs:element>
    </xs:sequence>
  </xs:complexType>

  <xs:complexType name="deliverShortMessageResponse">
    <xs:sequence>
      <xs:element name="deliverShortMessageReturn" type="xs:boolean"/>
    </xs:sequence>
  </xs:complexType>

  <xs:complexType name="deliverShortMessage">
    <xs:sequence>
      <xs:element name="sms" type="tns:smsMessage" minOccurs="0"/>
    </xs:sequence>
  </xs:complexType>

  <xs:complexType name="smsMessage">
    <xs:sequence>
      <xs:element name="content" type="xs:string" minOccurs="0"/>
    </xs:sequence>
  </xs:complexType>
</xs:schema>
```

my simple Endpoint class:

```
@Endpoint
public class MessageEndpoint {

    private static final String NAMESPACE_URI = "http://localhost:8080/ws/schema/oss";

    @PayloadRoot(namespace = NAMESPACE_URI, localPart = "DeliverShortMessageRequest")
    @ResponsePayload
    public DeliverShortMessageResponse deliverShortMessage(@RequestPayload DeliverShortMessageRequest deliverShortMessageRequest) {
        System.out.println("deliverShortMessage " + deliverShortMessageRequest);
        DeliverShortMessageResponse result = new DeliverShortMessageResponse();
        result.setDeliverShortMessageReturn(true);
        return result;
    }
}
```

spring-ws config:

```
<sws:annotation-driven />

<sws:interceptors>
        <bean id="validatingInterceptor"  class="org.springframework.ws.soap.server.endpoint.interceptor.PayloadValidatingInterceptor"
                    p:schema="/WEB-INF/schema.xsd"
                    p:validateRequest="true"
                    p:validateResponse="true"/>

        <bean id="loggingInterceptor" class="org.springframework.ws.server.endpoint.interceptor.PayloadLoggingInterceptor"/>
</sws:interceptors>

<sws:dynamic-wsdl id="subscription"
    portTypeName="SubscriptionPort"                                                         
    locationUri="/"                                                       
    targetNamespace="http://localhost:8080/ws/schema/oss">
  <sws:xsd location="/WEB-INF/schema.xsd"/>
</sws:dynamic-wsdl>

 <bean id="jaxbMarshaller" class="org.springframework.oxm.jaxb.Jaxb2Marshaller"
  p:contextPath="org.krams.tutorial.model"/>

<bean id="marshallingPayloadMethodProcessor" class="org.springframework.ws.server.endpoint.adapter.method.MarshallingPayloadMethodProcessor">
    <constructor-arg ref="jaxbMarshaller"/>
    <constructor-arg ref="jaxbMarshaller"/>
</bean>

<bean id="defaultMethodEndpointAdapter" class="org.springframework.ws.server.endpoint.adapter.DefaultMethodEndpointAdapter">
    <property name="methodArgumentResolvers">
        <list>
            <ref bean="marshallingPayloadMethodProcessor"/>
        </list> 
    </property>
    <property name="methodReturnValueHandlers">
        <list>
            <ref bean="marshallingPayloadMethodProcessor"/>
        </list>
    </property>
</bean>
```

When I searching an answers why it is happening I found replice like: 
[Spring-WS generates WSDL without operations](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1155809/spring-ws-generates-wsdl-without-operations) [Spring-WS WSDL Generation Problem](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3933106/spring-ws-wsdl-generation-problem) but as you can see my request and response objects have Request and Response suffix

do you have any ideas what i forgot? and why in wsdl i have no operation tag? it looks like he doesnt see Endpoint operation or there is some letter mismatch

Comment: For starters remove the `DefaultMethodEndpointAdapter` and `MarshallingPayloadMethodProcessor` and simply set the `marshaller` attribute on the `<sws:annotation-driven />` tag. Please add your xsd to your post.

Comment: schema.xsd was added to first post, i deleted DefaultMethodEndpointAdapter, MarshallingPayloadMethodProcessor (also i had to remove from mvc-ws-integration.xml param from messageDispatcher) and still wsdl file is wrong

Comment: You don't have elements only complexTypes. You should wrap your complex type in an `<xs:element name="nameOfYourType" />`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is that your xsd is wrong. You should wrap your complex types in an element.

```
<xs:element name="deliverShortMessageRequest">
  <xs:complexType>
    <xs:sequence>
      <xs:element name="parameters" minOccurs="0">
        <xs:complexType>
          <xs:sequence>
            <xs:element name="sms" type="tns:deliverShortMessage"/>
          </xs:sequence>
        </xs:complexType>
      </xs:element>
    </xs:sequence>
  </xs:complexType>
</xs:element />

<xs:element name="deliverShortMessageResponse">
  <xs:complexType >
    <xs:sequence>
      <xs:element name="deliverShortMessageReturn" type="xs:boolean"/>
    </xs:sequence>
  </xs:complexType>
</xs:element>
```